# PL/SQL pseudo Sequencing

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following scenario

```
ID    SEQ
--    ---
123   2
123   4
```

What I want to be able to do is produce a list of these values and fill in the missing numbers to a maximum number say 6 for example (which I have from another source) where those number do not exist with the ID on the table.

```
ID    NEW_SEQ
--    ---
123     1
123     2
123     3
123     4
123     5
123     6
```

Thanks
C

Comment: Where do you want this list? Do you want additional records inserted into the existing table>? Or do you want it as a cursor to scroll through? Or ... ?

Comment: What you need is an outer join with a `calendar table`

Comment: Why do you think you need a stored procedure for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generates a sequence of numbers from 1 through 6, cross joins with all the ids of the table to associate each of the sequence numbers with each id, then removes the already existing combinations.

```
SELECT t.id, s.seq
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM myTable) t
      ,(SELECT rownum AS seq
         FROM   dual
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6) s
MINUS
SELECT id, seq
  FROM myTable

ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of the numbers you want to use in OTHER_TABLE then I suggest you use an outer join, as in:

```
SELECT o.ID, o.NEW_SEQ
  FROM OTHER_TABLE o
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT ID, SEQ FROM MY_TABLE) t
    ON (o.ID = t.ID AND o.NEW_SEQ = t.SEQ)
  WHERE t.SEQ IS NULL
  ORDER BY o.ID, o.NEW_SEQ
```

The outer join will include all rows from the first table (OTHER_TABLE, in this case) joined with the rows which exist from the second table (here, MY_TABLE). If there is a row in OTHER_TABLE which does not have a matching row in MY_TABLE, the fields from MY_TABLE will be NULL - thus, by checking for t.SEQ being NULL you're able to find the rows which exist in OTHER_TABLE but which are not in MY_TABLE.

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d9f3c/2).

Share and enjoy.